# URL mismatch in POST data CakePHP 3

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I got a problem with a fresh install of CakePHP 3.6.

My app is intalled on Apache server in sub folder.

```
/home/{USER}/public_html/dbot/dbot
```

I got this error when i tried to submit form data.

```
URL mismatch in POST data (expected '/dbot/dbot/users/users/request-reset-password' but found '/users/users/request-reset-password')
```

The action of the form is set to:

```
action="/dbot/dbot/users/users/request-reset-password"
```

Can you help me (Sorry about quality of post, I'm in a rush a little bit). Thanks !

Comment: Show us all your .htaccess && app config files

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was a problem with the SecurityComponent. See [ref1](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/issues/11944) [ref2](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/pull/11954/commits/e2ed51f20a35966228a298be943757b727dd0360)

Solution is to upgrade to CakePHP 3.6.1 to include the fix.